# Uniqueness error in has_many nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class student with has_many tests. The test class has a student_id, marks, name. Here the test name should be unique. The test is a nested attribute for student. So the parameters are this way:

```
:student => {:first_name => "abc", 
             :email => "dfsdf@sfdsdsd.bbb", 
             :tests_attributes => { "0" => {:name => "bgc", :marks => "470"}}}
```

I have a problem with update. If I update_attributes with the tests_attributes, it throws a validation error saying the name for test is not unique. I am actually addressing the same record here. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Do you have **`uniqueness validation for name`** in `Test` model? If so you have to remove it to make this work.

Comment: Are you treating the validation in the scope of the `student`, or just generally has to be unique in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `models` (& `validations`), it's going to be quite difficult to diagnose your error directly.

--

**Nested Attributes**

We've done something like this, and found that your nested data is passed to the child model as if it were receiving a new object (without being nested). This means if you've got [validates uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) for that model, it should be okay:

```
#app/models/test.rb
Class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
   validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

Reason I write this is because there's a method called [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aAssociations%3a%3aClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses), which basically allows you to access the `parent` model data in your `child` model

--

**Update**

I think the problem will likely lie with your use of `update_attributes`. Problem being you're trying to update both the `student` and the `test` attributes at one time.

I'm not sure exactly why this would be a problem, but I'd test this:

```
#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
    def update
        @student = Student.find params[:id]
        @student.test.update(name: params[:test_name], marks: params[:marks])
    end
end
```

I think if you can explain your methodology a little more, it will be much more helpful. I.E are you trying to update `student` or `test`? If you're updating `student` & adding a new `test`, how are you updating the studet?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply guys. I ended up finding the answer myself. I did have a uniqueness validation for name.
I had a situation where initially I wouldn't know the student but have only his details. So I would have to create this hash and pass it to update. The trick to not trying to create a new record for the same name in test is to pass the actual record's ID along with it. This solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Nested Attributes**

I think the problem with nested_attributes. For update need to pass nested_attributes with ID.
Ex.

```
:student => {:first_name => "abc", 
             :email => "dfsdf@sfdsdsd.bbb", 
             :tests_attributes => { "0" => {id: 1, :name => "bgc", :marks => "470"}}}
```

I have tried below-given example it is worked for me:

**Update**

```
 #app/controllers/students_controller.rb
    class StudentsController < ApplicationController
        def update
            @student = Student.find params[:id]
            @student.update_attributes(student_params)
        end

        private

        def student_params
          params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :email, 
          tests_attributes: [:id, :name, :marks])
        end
    end
```